# C# Putting an Image into an ImageList changes the color of the Image slightly?

Tags: c#, colors, imagelist

I'm not sure if this is intentional, but I've done some experimenting and apparently, when you put an Image into an ImageList, the color of the Image gets *slightly* changed.

For example, I have an Image (144x144) filled with the color ARGB (255, 247, 215, 193). After putting it into an ImageList and then displaying the Image in a PictureBox, the color has changed to ARGB (255, 239, 214, 198). A barely noticeable difference, but a difference nonetheless.

Is there a reason why this is happening, or is it some kind of bug with ImageLists? Is there a way to avoid this kind of color offset while using ImageLists to display Images?

Here is some example code that exhibits this behavior:

```
        string filePath = directoryPath + "/Images/Test/Test.png";

        Bitmap TestImage1 = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(filePath);
        MessageBox.Show(TestImage1.GetPixel(0, 0).ToString());

        ImageList IL = new ImageList();
        IL.ImageSize = new Size(144, 144);
        IL.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(filePath));
        Bitmap TestImage2 = (Bitmap)IL.Images[0];
        MessageBox.Show(TestImage2.GetPixel(0, 0).ToString());
```

The first MessageBox displays "Color [A=255, R=247, G=215, B=193]".
The second MessageBox displays "Color [A=255, R=239, G=214, B=198]".

Here is a sample of the ever-so-slight color difference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7beR.png

Comment: Would you care to post some example code that exhibits this behaviour?

Comment: Example code added.

Comment: What is the `ColorDepth` of the `ImageList` and `Bitmap` images you're using?

Comment: ColorDepth (PixelFormat):

TestImage1 is Format24bppRgb
TestImage2 is Format32bppArgb

Not sure what these mean or how they got this way, but yeah.

Comment: ImageList ColorDepth is "Depth8Bit"

Comment: Ah I added the line "IL.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth24Bit;" and the color has been fixed! Thank you!

Comment: Unless you changed the `ColorDepth`, it will default to `Depth8Bit`, which has, at most, 3 bits per color channel.  Adding anything with more bits is going to involve mapping colors.  If you want to be truly color-safe, with transparency, you want 32-bit color

Comment: Hmm noted, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a couple of lines which make it hard to determine exactly what's going on.

Why is `IL.ImageSize = new Size(144, 144);` in there? What does that do to your image? I took it out.

Next you're re-loading the image when you do `IL.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(filePath));`. It would be much more instructive to do `IL.Images.Add(TestImage1);` to see if the reference changes.

If you run this code:

```
    Bitmap TestImage1 = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(filePath);
    Console.WriteLine(TestImage1.GetPixel(0, 0).ToString());

    ImageList IL = new ImageList();
    IL.Images.Add(TestImage1);
    Bitmap TestImage2 = (Bitmap)IL.Images[0];

    Console.WriteLine(TestImage2.GetPixel(0, 0).ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(TestImage1.GetPixel(0, 0).ToString());

    Console.WriteLine(TestImage1.Equals(TestImage2));
```

Then you'll get something like:

```
Color [A=255, R=249, G=249, B=249]
Color [A=255, R=255, G=251, B=240]
Color [A=255, R=249, G=249, B=249]
False
```

This is telling you that when you add an image to the image list it is creating a new image. The references are not the same.

If you look at the source for `ImageList` you'll see all sorts of code like this:

```
    bitmap1 = new Bitmap((Image) bitmap2, this.ImageSize);
    if (ownsBitmap)
      bitmap2.Dispose();
    ownsBitmap = true;
```

It's doing a lot of image management and creating copies all over the place. So just assume that the `ImageList` never keeps a reference to your original image.

Comment: Hmm the line IL.ImageSize = new Size(144, 144); is in there because ImageLists default to size 32x32. So if I display an Image that's 144x144 in a pictureBox I have to set the ImageList's size to that as well, or else it shows up as a 32x32 image.

Comment: But yeah I guess it has no relevance to the rest of the example code, it was just a part of my original code I left in there >< Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @J.Doe - The `ImageSize` property is a big hint that the `ImageList` recreates images on-the-fly.